# Python Macros: Use Cases?

Tags: python, macros, lisp, scheme

If Python had a macro facility similar to Lisp/Scheme (something like [MetaPython](https://code.google.com/p/metapython/)), how would you use it?

If you are a Lisp/Scheme programmer, what sorts of things do you use macros for (other than things that have a clear syntactic parallel in Python such as a while loop)?

Comment: Are you aware of the Logix project? http://www.livelogix.com/logix/

Comment: I had looked at Logix a long time ago, but not recently.  It is an interesting approach.  Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @codeape: Link is broken

Comment: Yes, unfortunately and regretfully, I would probably wind up use them (when I didn't need to).

Comment: Link to Logix project: http://logix-language.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some examples of lisp macros:

- [ITERATE](http://common-lisp.net/project/iterate) which is a funny and extensible loop facility
- [CL-YACC](http://www.pps.jussieu.fr/~jch/software/cl-yacc/)/[FUCC](http://common-lisp.net/project/fucc) that are parser generators that generate parsers at compile time
- [CL-WHO](http://www.weitz.de/cl-who/) which allows specifying html documents with static and dynamic parts
- [Parenscript](http://common-lisp.net/project/parenscript/) which is a javascript code generator
- Various simple code-wrappers, e.g., error handlers (I have a with-gtk-error-message-handler that executes code and shows GtkMessageDialog if unhandled error occurs), executors (e.g., given a code, execute it in different thread; I have a within-main-thread macro that executes code in different threads; [PCall](http://marijn.haverbeke.nl/pcall/) library uses macros to wrap code to be executed concurrently)
- GUI builders with macros (e.g., specify widgets hierarchy and widgets' properties and have a macro generate code for creation of all widgets)
- Code generators that use external resources during compilation time. E.g., a macro that processes C headers and generates FFI code or a macro that generates classes definitions based on database schema
- Declarative FFI. E.g., specifying the foreign structures, functions, their argument types and having macros to generate corresponding lisp structures, functions with type mapping and marshaling code
- Continuations-based web frameworks for Common Lisp use macros that transform the code into CPS (continuation passing style) form.

Comment: -1: Examples from lisp don't apply very well to Python.  If these can be done in Python without macros, then these aren't really use cases for Python are they?

Comment: The only way I see to do most of these in Python is extending the syntax.  But that's always true: if you get the language maintainer to extend the language for every feature you might want, that's essentially what macros do.  Only with a macro facility, you don't need to fork the language or ask Guido every time.

Comment: S.Lott: The question is not about applicability of use cases, but about actual use cases. Strictly speaking, when you have eval(), you can do everything without macros. I think that such kind of an argument is counter-productive.
I do not think that every one of mentioned examples can be done in Python without losing important features (e.g., minimal/small runtime overhead, compile-time error detection, integration with the rest of the language).

Comment: "You can do everything with eval()" is only true if you're willing to put all your code in strings, and write your own parser/translator. But if those are true, you don't even need eval(): any Turing-equivalent language is sufficient.

Comment: Ken: it is possible to have eval without parser. Some lisps (e.g., newlisp) have F-Exprs. Fexpr is a kind of function that accepts unevaluated arguments as expressions (AST subtrees) and it can decide what to do with them: eval, change and eval, discard, etc. Of course, there are huge problems with fexprs.

Comment: The other case being over looked here is early/eager evaluation at compile time.  As dmitry-vk mentions in his answer, a parser library that generates parser state machines (very costly) at bytecode-compilation-time.  python doesn't "compile" in the traditional sense, but it does convert source to bytecode and then caches it.  It would be awfully useful to cache those expensive state machines.

Answer (score 16):

This is a somewhat late answer, but [MacroPy](https://github.com/lihaoyi/macropy) is a new project of mine to bring macros to Python. We have a pretty substantial list of demos, all of which are use cases which require macros to implement, for example providing an extremely concise way of declaring classes:

```
@case
class Point(x, y)

p = Point(1, 2)
print p.x   # 1
print p     # Point(1, 2)
```

MacroPy has been used to implement features such as:

- Case Classes, easy [Algebraic Data Types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type) from Scala
- Pattern Matching from the Functional Programming world
- Tail-call Optimization
- Quasiquotes, a quick way to manipulate fragments of a program
- String Interpolation, a common feature in many languages, and Pyxl.
- Tracing and Smart Asserts
- PINQ to SQLAlchemy, a clone of LINQ to SQL from C#
- Quick Lambdas from Scala and Groovy,
- Parser Combinators, inspired by [Scala's](http://www.suryasuravarapu.com/2011/04/scala-parser-combinators-win.html).

Check out the linked page to find out more; I think I can confidently say that the use cases we demonstrate far surpass anything anyone's suggested so far on this thread =D

Comment: +1: You definitely get why macros should exist much better than anyone else who has responded. Having said that, I dislike your library. Using the macros created by it seems more complicated than necessary, and writing macros with it is far, far more complicated than necessary.

Answer (score 14):

I believe that macros run counter to Python's culture. Macros in Lisp allow the [big ball of mud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_ball_of_mud) approach; you get to redefine the language to become more suited to your problem domain. Conversely Pythonic code uses the most natural built in feature of Python to solve a problem, instead of solving it in a way that would be more natural in a different language.

Macros are inherently unpythonic.

Comment: That's kind of begging the question, though, isn't it?  If macros were added to the language, by that logic, they'd become "pythonic", just as decorators, list comprehensions, the conditional expression, metaclasses, etc. would not have been considered "pythonic" before they were added as built-in features to the language.  What makes macros less pythonic than, say, using sys._getframe() and metaclasses?

Comment: You'd be right, but this is usually in reference to PEP 20 http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/ and the like which outline the general philosophy of the language. In this case, I think macros are likely to go against several of the linked guidelines.

Comment: I'm familiar with the Zen of Python; I'm just not convinced that macros are necessarily in opposition to it.

Comment: I think it would depend how they're implemented. Looking at the metapython link provided in the question, I see a few problems.

Comment: Pythonic style is like the style of a font. 
List comprehensions et al. are like different letters in the Python font. Macros are like meta rules to let you generate your own font.

Comment: Macros aren't necessary -- which makes them unpythonic.  There aren't any sensible use cases.  Examples from other languages don't apply here.  Macros are a source-level workaround to language gaps.

Comment: Macros are a point in a space of trade-offs in language design. They tradeoff performance vs dynamism (by limiting the neccesity to call eval at runtime, allowing compiler to apply logic for optimization, type-checking, type-inference). Macros are neccessary to be able to introduce useful abstractions while retaining ability to do useful optimizations. This is one of the reasons why Common Lisp implementations are fast and CPython is slow - one can not easily remove interpreter overhead.

Comment: @dmitry I think the tradeoff is between powerful abstractions and code clarity. Performance seems to be unrelated.

Comment: rossfabricant: have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fexpr . Fexprs allow same kind of code clarity and are more powerful  than macros (in terms of computations that are possible with them; everything that is possible to do with macros is possible to do with fexprs; but not the other way).

Comment: At the core, macros are about inventing new (better?) ways of saying the same thing.  Doing the same thing only different sounds very un-pythonic, probably.  Consult "import this".

Answer (score 5):

There's a [mailing list posting](http://lists.warhead.org.uk/pipermail/iwe/2005-July/000130.html) ([archive.org mirror](http://web.archive.org/web/20080117093622/http://lists.warhead.org.uk/pipermail/iwe/2005-July/000130.html)) which explains this rather well. The post is about Perl, but it applies to Python just as well.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one real-world example I came across that would be trivial with macros or real metaprogramming support, but has to be done with CPython bytecode manipulation due to absence of both in Python:

http://www.aminus.net/dejavu/chrome/common/doc/2.0a/html/intro.html#cpython

This is how the problem is solved in Common Lisp using a combination of regular macros, and read-macros to extend the syntax (it could have been done without the latter, but not the former):

http://clsql.b9.com/manual/csql-find.html

The same problem solved in Smalltalk using closures and metaprogramming (Smalltalk is one of the few single-dispatch OO languages that actually gets message passing right):

http://people.csail.mit.edu/gregs/ll1-discuss-archive-html/msg02096.html

Here I tried to implement the Smalltalk approach in Common Lisp, which is a good illustration of how metaprogramming is poorly supported in the latter:

http://carcaddar.blogspot.com/2009/04/closure-oriented-metaprogramming-via.html

Answer (score 4):

In lisp, macros are just another way to abstract ideas.

This is an example from an incomplete ray-tracer written in clojure:

```
(defmacro per-pixel
  "Macro.
Excecutes body for every pixel. Binds i and j to the current pixel coord."
  [i j & body]
  `(dotimes [~i @width]
     (dotimes [~j @height]
       ~@body)))
```

If you want to do something to every pixel with coordinates (i,j), say, draw a black pixel if i is even, you would write:

```
(per-pixel i,j
  (if (even? i)
    (draw-black i,j)))
```

This is not possible to do without macros because @body can mean anything inside (per-pixel i j @body)

Something like this would be possible in python as well. You need to use decorators.
You can't do everything you can do with lisp macros, but they are very powerful

Check out this decorator tutorial: 
http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240808

Comment: in Lisp: Write a function PER-PIXEL and pass the body as another function. No macro needed.

Comment: Yes, I also fail to understand why this is a good macro example.

Comment: You don't need macros for that in Lisp. You also don't need decorators for that in Python. It's just a multidimensional "foreach" type function. Why not per_pixel(callback) where per_pixel calls callback with j and i. In Lisp, callback could be a lambda. In Python it could too (but, pythonically, lambdas are limited to being single expressions).

Answer (score 3):

Some uses cases I have seen before include making [class factories](http://code.google.com/p/metapython/wiki/Tutorial) or [stripping logging](http://blog.pythonisito.com/2009/03/announcing-metapython-macros-for-python.html) statements out of production code.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Python needs macros, because they are useful for 2 things:

1. Creating a DSL or more eloquent syntax for something (Lisp LOOP macro is a nice example). In this case, Python philosophy decided against it deliberately. If there is some explicit notation you're missing, you can always ask for a PEP.
2. Making things faster by precomputing things at compile time. Python isn't oriented to speed, so you can always use a function instead.

I am not saying macros are wrong, just that they don't fit Python philosophy. You can always do without them without much code duplication, because you have duck typing and operator overloading.

And as a side note, I would much rather see Lisp's restarts in Python than macros.

Comment: The "Domain" part in Domain Specific Language does not mean a new, stupider way of writing "for" loops.

http://domaindrivendesign.org/

Comment: So Python's built-in macro facility is the PEP? :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'd use it to wrap `yield` to enable me to build more powerful generator pipelines.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the only way features can be added to Python the language is through a PEP (Python Enhancement Proposal). This can be slow, and doesn't help you in the cases when you want to add a feature to the language that is only useful for your use case.

For example, [there's a PEP to add a do-while loop](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0315/). This will probably be added to Python, but the PEP was created in 2003. I'd like to write `do-while` loops today, and I could do that if Python had macros.

Similarly, there was a [PEP to add labelled break and continue](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3136/) but this was rejected. If labelled break statements would make my code clearer, I could implement them with a macro.

PEPs aside, I would also like an `unless` macro. Rather than writing:

```
if not is_superman():
    dodge_bullet()
```

I could write:

```
unless is_superman():
    dodge_bullet()
```

I'd like a `case` macro (often called `cond` in Lisp). Rather than writing:

```
if x == FOO:
    do_stuff_with_foos()
elif x == BAR:
    do_stuff_with_bars()
elif x == BAZ:
    do_stuff_with_bazs()
```

I could write:

```
switch x:
   case FOO:
       do_stuff_with_foos()
   case BAR:
       do_stuff_with_bars()
   case BAZ:
       do_stuff_with_bazs()
```

These would be straightforward to implement as macros. More complex, useful macros would include:

- Ruby style string interpolation e.g. `"hello there {user}"` (probably best implemented as a reader macro)
- Pattern matching

Currently, these are only features in other languages. With macros, I could add them to Python. I could even write PEPs that included an example implementation. (Some PEPs already do this, but they are forced to modify the C source of the interpreter itself.)

Comment: Nice simple examples.  I would add a `let` expression and `ifelse` function to your list.

Answer (score 1):

Hy,
For my own use, I created a Python module (Espy) that allows macro definitions with arguments, loop and conditional code generation:
You create a source.espy file, then launch the appropriate function, then source.py is generated.

It allows syntaxes as following:

```
macro repeat(arg1):
    for i in range(%arg1%):
        socket
    print "stop"
   ...
repeat(5):
    print "Hi everybody"
    print "See you soon"
```

is equivalent to:

```
...
for i in range(5):
    print "Hi everybody"
    print "See you soon"
print "stop"
```

Other syntax:

```
macro doit(arg1):
    for i in %arg1%:
        socket suit(arg2):
            socket
            print %arg2%
        socket check(arg3):
            if %arg2%==%arg3%:
                socket
...
#use
doit(range(10)):
    suit(result):
        result=i*i
    check(result,25):
        print "I knew that 5*5 == 25"
```

is equivalent to:

```
for i in range(10):
    result=i*i
    print result
    if result==25:
        print "I knew that 5*5 == 25"
```

More, Espy has 2 functions: "macro for" and "macro if". An example:

```
macro for v in [6,10,12,20,23]:
    macro if 7<%v%<22:
        True:
            print "At %v%, I'm awake."
        False:
            print "At %v%, I'm sleeping."
```

is translated by Espy in:

```
print "At 6, I'm sleeping."
print "At 10, I'm awake."
print "At 12, I'm awake."
print "At 20, I'm awake."
print "At 23, I'm sleeping."
```

Complete documentation and free download can be found here: http://elp.chronocv.fr

I use this module in many cases. It permits more structured and shorter codes. With it I generated 65000 lines of clear and efficient python code from 1000 lines of espy code for a new chess engine project (still in progress).

If Python could include macros in futur release, it'd become more impressive.

Answer (score 1):

I want to use macro to enable sql statement in python code. -
select * from table1

Answer (score 0):

Read "The Lambda Papers" so you might find out generally why one would take advtage of macros at all.

You should start with ‘AIM-353 Lambda:The Ultimate Imperative’ and follow it with ‘AIM-443 Lambda: The Ultimate GOTO’. Both may be found here:

http://library.readscheme.org/page1.html

Answer (score 0):

Possibly if you want the source code at runtime such as for debugging (say printf debugging an expression's value with the name of it so you don't have to write it twice).

[The only way I could think of to do it in python is to pass a string to eval.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573023/python-is-there-no-better-way-to-get-the-expression-in-a-debug-function)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'd like instead of

```
print >> sys.stderr, "abc"
```

to write

```
err "abc"
```

in some scripts which have many debug printout statements.

I can do

```
import sys
err = sys.stderr
```

and then

```
print >> err, "abc"
```

which is shorter, but that still takes too many characters on the line.

Comment: If you just define a function, you can write `err("abc")`, which is surely better than `print >> err, "abc"`, and not that much worse than `err "abc"`…

Comment: Good point: `def err(*args): print >> sys.stderr, ' '.join(map(str, args))`.

Answer (score 0):

Coming from a C-world, I'd really appreciate being able to do efficient logging of rich messages.  Instead of writing

```
if logger.level > logger.DEBUG:
    logger.log('%s' % (an_expensive_call_that_gives_useful_info(),))
```

with macros, one could instead do something like

```
DEBUG('%s' % (an_expensive_call_that_gives_useful_info(),))
```